# Apps from Google Play Store can access Google Drive and create configuration files, how do I view them?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Google Play store (i.e. Android) apps can be granted access to view, edit and delete app specific files in my personal Google Drive.

Without using API and without using the Google Play app, if I am logged in to the Google account on a browser, how do I view these "app configuration" files?

If I uninstall the app, how can I be sure my Google Drive space is free'ed up?

Comment: When users uninstall the app from My Drive, the application data folder is deleted. App-specific data such as configuration files is stored in a special hidden folder so you can’t search for it manually. However, if you want to delete app configuration files save on your Google Drive, you can go to [https://drive.google.com/drive/settings](https://drive.google.com/drive/settings) \> click "Manage Apps" \> find the app you want to delete configuration files \> click “OPTIONS” \> click “Delete hidden files”.

Comment: Great! I'll post it as an answer and by doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When users uninstall the app from My Drive, the application data folder is deleted. App-specific data such as configuration files is stored in a special hidden folder so you can’t search for it manually. However, if you want to delete app configuration files  save on your Google Drive, you can go to https://drive.google.com/drive/settings > click "Manage Apps" > find the app you want to delete configuration files > click “OPTIONS” > click “Delete hidden files”.

**Reference:**

[Store application-specific data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata)